# Picture Library with custom url for every image

Tags: picture-library

I need to have a picture slideshow library with a custom url column for every new item, on clicking on which the custom link to the image (which would be a document) should open, I am unable to use the custom url column and the link should be dynamic with every image. Please share the solution as it is quite urgent. Thanks

Comment: If 2013, have you checked out the Promoted Links app? It shows images like the default image library, but instead opens a custom link when clicked.

Comment: Can you explain more? All files in libraries have a unique URL out of the box.

Comment: I ll explain the question: Have a picture library which needs to be displayed as  a slide show in the page, clicking on each picture, it should open a document.
I have created a column in my picture library as New Link and has provided the url for each document (The document opens fine.). I need to link the image with the documents in the slide show webpart. 
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and not being able to find a solution. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically update the url column with value like `"http://example/siteassets/image"+i+".png"`' for items. 'i' you can assign based on the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the slide show of pictures. But you can create the static images(like icon) and open the documents on click of the image. Steps to follow:

1. Add picture library to upload your images.
2. Add one more app using "Promoted Links" list template.
3. Add items in promoted links. Provide the image URL in "Background image location" field and the link to document in "Link Location" field.
4. Then you can select the "Tiles" view on list to show the images and open the documents on click of images. (Or you can one create new page on site and add list web part of promoted links on page).
5. "Link Behavior" is additional column in promoted links, which is having options to open the link in new tab or in dialog box.

You can get help from [here](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-promoted-links-list-app-part-1), to add the promoted links.

But make a note, this will be the static images and not the slide show.

Comment: have you tried this?